# Installing Ubuntu without losing files

Tags: system-installation

Windows 7 is running on my PC. Is there a way I can **clean install** Ubuntu with the same partition without losing files.

Comment: Only in a virtual machine. Installing it on real hardware would require creating new partitions.

Comment: Do you want to keep Windows or just your personal data files?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

1. backup your data
2. install ubuntu
3. restore your backuped data.

How to backup data: Copy the data to a usb drive or CD or something

Answer (score 1):

## Remove everything and install Ubuntu

1. Backup whatever you need to a USB/external hard drive etc.
2. Install Ubuntu - choosing the 'Use entire disk' option.
3. Restore data from the backup

## Install Ubuntu - but keep Windows and all your files

1. Install 'Ubuntu' - choosing the 'Install alongside Windows' option -- but still **back up your data first**.  Things can go wrong during an install.

Answer (score 0):

If you have important files on other than system partition, Yes, you can. If on the same -> Backup important data first.
But if youre system UEFI capable it would be nice to backup data, create GPT partition sheme and clean install on GPT partition.